# Preserving order in a graphql query using filter

Tags: mongodb, graphql, react-fullstack

I have a list of MongoDB _ids that correspond to their appropriate documents. Is there a way to write a graphQL query that will return a corresponding list of documents in the same order as their mongoDB _ids?

I know you can do filter{ _ids: $listOfIDs } to get a payload, but the payload does not have the order that corresponds to the order of the list of _ids.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976826/how-to-implement-graphql-scalar-for-mongodb-sort-property-found-in-collection-fi

Comment: hmmm I don't think so because it deals with the sorting using mongoDB in the back-end I believe, not with the sorting being done at the query

Comment: filtering is implementation dependent ... resolver is the place when you can try to implement you required logic